# MySQL UPDATE statement is not updating the associated table

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I have the following code:

```
$query = "UPDATE jobs SET `ipt` = '$ipt', `prejobform` = '$prejobform', `fileddate` = '$fileddate' WHERE `job_id` = '$jobid'";

  $result = mysql_query($query);


     if (!$result) {
        //ERROR LOGGER HERE
        echo mysql_error();
     }
     else {
        header('Location: view_job.php?jobid='.$jobid);
     }
```

This code is redirecting like it is behaving correctly, but when I check the database, the fields have not been updated. I'm sure the problem is something simple that I'm missing, but I'm at a loss to find the problem.

Comment: What are the values of `$ipt`, `$prejobform`, `$fileddate`, `$jobid`? What is the result of `mysql_affected_rows()` after the query?

Comment: It might help if you echo the query string once it's constructed and see if there are any obvious problems with it (and paste it here if you don't see any).

Comment: Try to execute the same query directly on MySQL, either from the console or a client -- if you are sure that the PHP code has constructed the SQL correctly. It is possible that the query did execute, but 0 rows got updated based on the specified values.

Comment: first chech your $ipt', '$prejobform','$fileddate'  variables and $jobid they have values or not ???

Comment: I feel stupid, the $job_id was checking against the wrong field in the table, so it was coming back with 0 rows affected. I changed it to the right field, and all is well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For an `UPDATE` query, `mysql_query` returns true if the query succeeded (was parsed and executed correctly), not only if it did really update any rows.
2. If the underlying table is `InnoDB` and you have started a transaction earlier, the query won't commit transaction implicitly and it will roll back when you exit the script or disconnect.